# file extension of the file types cdump, incident, trace

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, filegroups

I need to know the file extension of the file types cdump, incident, trace, alert.

Actually I want to create files of the above types manually using `mkfile` command.

There are no existing files of above type but only main empty directories exist, may be since my server is fresh and didn't get opportunity to create these files.

If you mention even the directory (last sub-directory) in which these type of files are stored, would be a favor to me.

My ultimate purpose is to delete these files using `adrci purge` command which is my test scenario.

I am using Solaris OS and oracle Release 11.2.0.2.0.

Comment: I'd advise against deleting the alert log

Comment: @mahendra which is the purpose of manually creating these files?

Comment: @Ste Perhaps to test out that deletion is working correctly?